# How to reload a tableView once a value has been appended to an array in swift 4.0

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

There I am having a problem reloading a tableView once a value has been appended to an array.

Here's my code

```
//
//  HomeViewController.swift
//  um
//
//  Created by Arnav on 17/09/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Arnav. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth


class HomeTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var questions = [Question]()

    override  func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
//       var postQuestion = Question(questionName: "Hi", created_by: "Bye")
//       print(postQuestion.name)
//       print(postQuestion.created)

        loadQuestions()

    }

    var list = ["milk", "bread"]

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return list.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }


    func loadQuestions() {
        Database.database().reference().child("questionPosts").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
                //var questionName = dict["name"] as! String
                //var created_by = dict["email"] as! String
                let questionTitle = dict["name"] as? String ?? ""
                let created_by = dict["email"] as? String ?? ""

                self.list.append(questionTitle)
            }
        }
    }
```

This code is just added a new value to the list array and the table view displays whats from the list array but when I append something new to the list array and run it on the simulator the new value doesn't

Comment: you just need to wright tableviewname.reloadData()

Comment: @SagarBhut check the definition: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wright#Verb

Answer (score 2):

You can use the property observer `didSet`.

```
var questions = [Question]() {
    didSet {
        Dispatch.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

For more information [click here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html).

Answer (score 2):

After adding the new element to the `list`, call `insertRowAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation` on your tableView as follows:

```
self.list.append(questionTitle)
let indexPath = IndexPath(row:self.list.count - 1, section:0)
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation:.default)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an outlet for your tableview and once your data is loaded you can call

```
tableview.reloadData()
```

Alternatively, you can cell the above function on the `didSet` of your array like below:

```
var questions = [Question]() {
    didSet {
        // because we perform this operation on the main thread, it is safe
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

`didSet` will be called every time you change something in your questions array

Comment: What if network call will append 1000 item into the array. Will this reload function will called 1000 item inside this didSet? If yes then what will be the another approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth



class HomeTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {



    var questions = [Question]()

    override  func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
//       var postQuestion = Question(questionName: "Hi", created_by: "Bye")
//       print(postQuestion.name)
//       print(postQuestion.created)

        loadQuestions()
        yourtableView.reloadData()

    }






    var list = ["milk", "bread"]




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        return list.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }


    func loadQuestions() {
        Database.database().reference().child("questionPosts").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
                //var questionName = dict["name"] as! String
                //var created_by = dict["email"] as! String
                let questionTitle = dict["name"] as? String ?? ""
                let created_by = dict["email"] as? String ?? ""

                self.list.append(questionTitle) 




            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: please check my ans. you have to just reload tableview inside your viewdidLoad

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I remove all items in a previous array then reload in again.

I tried "didset" to reload anytime an array changed but no luck.

So, simply do

> yourarray.removeall()
>
> tableview.reloadData()